# MapReduce: Log file locations for stdout and std err

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

If I output some message thru stdout (System.out in Java) and stderr (System.err in Java) in Mapper and Reducer, where can I see them in  task tracker node? I guess the directory location is configurable thru some parameter as well?

Answer (score 2):

This might depend on which distribution you are using but with our cdh3 setup, we can find them  under /usr/lib/hadoop-0.20/logs/userlogs// on the node where the task ran. For example, stderr would be under:

```
/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20/logs/userlogs/job_201207010432_5284/attempt_201207010432_5284_m_000214_0/stderr
```

If you have access to the job tracker UI for your cluster, you can also access them through there (which is what I typically do).